# Makefile: use multiline string as input for command

Tags: makefile, typescript

I want to use a multi-line, json-encoded string as input to
a command in a makefile.  Right now, nothing seems to get passed to
the command `watchman-typescript` or `watchman-debug`.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: typescript
typescript:
    tsc --target ES5 ts/main.ts

.PHONY: watch
watch:
    watchman watch .

define WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER =
["trigger", "./ts", {
  "name": "tsTrigger",
  "expression": ["suffix", "ts"],
  "command": ["make", "typescript"]
}]
endef

.PHONY: watchman-typescript
watchman-typescript:
    watchman -j '$(WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER)'

.PHONY: watchman-debug
watchman-debug:
    echo $(WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER)
```

Comment: Does the JSON have to be passed to `watchman` as multiple lines, or do you just want to be able to write it that way in the makefile for readability?

Comment: I was going for readability and trying to avoid backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this does not appear to be possible in make itself -- make ends up interpreting every line of the variable as a command in the recipe -- there is a workaround: You can export the variable as a shell variable and reference that in the command. That is:

```
define WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER =
["trigger", "./ts", {
  "name": "tsTrigger",
  "expression": ["suffix", "ts"],
  "command": ["make" "typescript"]
}]
endef

# export as shell variable
export WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER

# ...

# use shell variable in the command. $$ in make means $ in the shell command.
watchman-typescript:
    watchman -j "$$WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER"
```

Answer (score 1):

In makefiles, you can use the [line continuation character](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Lines.html) `\` to split something over multiple lines:

```
define WATCHMAN_TYPESCRIPT_TRIGGER = \
["trigger", "./ts", { \
  "name": "tsTrigger", \
  "expression": ["suffix", "ts"], \
  "command": ["make" "typescript"] \
}] \
endef
```